# How to access my Namenode GUI in hadoop outside the GCP instance in browser

Tags: hadoop, networking, google-cloud-platform, installation

I just set up single node HADOOP setup on a GCP instance. Doing JPS command is showing all the processes are running fine.

I want to access the GUI of my namenode. I am using http://localhost:50070/ on my laptop browser.

**It shows** `This site can’t be reached`

**Coresite.xml**

```
hduser@laptop:~$ vi /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description></description>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

**Mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
  <description>
  </description>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

**Solution attempted:**
I have tried replacing my values in `<value>` tag with the public DNS of GCP instance but then the namenode stopped working.

Anyone having any idea here what i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem:

1. you need to use your public IP and port number
2. check your firewall setting it should allow all the traffic in inbound rules in
   AWS and firewall setting in GCP